# Mapping object properties, excluding types

Tags: c#, asp.net

What i currently use

```
public static void MapObjectPropertyValues(object e1, object e2)
    {
        foreach (var p in e1.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (e2.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name) != null)
            {
                p.SetValue(e1, e2.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).GetValue(e2, null), null);
            }   

        }
    }
```

I want to pass a third parameter, a generic list of types that i want to exclude from the mapping. For example strings and booleans. And check if `p` is of a type in the list. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `p.PropertyType` property to exclude assignment if the types match exactly.

```
public static void MapObjectPropertyValues(object e1,
                  object e2,
                  IEnumerable<Type> excludedTypes)
{
    foreach (var p in e1.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (e2.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name) != null && 
        // next line added
        !(excludedTypes.Contains(p.PropertyType)))
        {
            p.SetValue(e1, e2.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).GetValue(e2, null), null);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please provide an example when calling the method? Ive never used an IEnumerable before, but i suppose its similar to a generic list?

Comment: IEnumerable<T> is one of the interfaces List<T> implements, meaning you can simply provide a List<Type> as the parameter.  (The parameter will also accept enumerable objects that aren't lists, such as arrays and sets.)

Comment: I tried adding `bool` and ´Boolean´, but none of them works. What would be eqvivalent of a bool in this case?

Comment: typeof() is the way to go i suppose